# Issue to send the right data to the Blade View

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel

When i dd() the variable after applying a filter, i get the right number of arrays. But when i pass this array to the laravel blade view i get all the records.

Heres the code.

```
$user = Auth::User();
$boards = Board::all();
$s = 'Tom Cruise';
$finalarray = [];
foreach ($boards as $board) {
    foreach ($board['owner'] as $owner) {
        if ($owner == $s)
            $finalarray = array_prepend($finalarray, $board);
    }
}
return view('layouts.board')
    ->with(compact('user', $user))
    ->with(compact('boards', collect($finalarray)));
```

here is the sample data

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c2e21453c06144b6038f39"),
        "name" : "board",
        "description" : "with slug",
        "owner" : {
                "id" : "58bc562553c06113f130bbb3",
                "name" : "Joker"
        },
        "slug" : "board",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T17:27:48.438Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T17:27:48.438Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c2e21853c06144b6038f3a"),
        "name" : "board",
        "description" : "with slug",
        "owner" : {
                "id" : "58bc562553c06113f130bbb3",
                "name" : "Joker"
        },
        "slug" : "board",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T17:27:52.073Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T17:27:52.073Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c3097b53c06144b6038f40"),
        "name" : "Board by Tom Cruise",
        "description" : "afgf",
        "owner" : {
                "id" : "58c3090b53c06144b6038f3f",
                "name" : "Tom Cruise"
        },
        "slug" : "board_by_tom_cruise",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T20:15:55.132Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T20:15:55.132Z")
}
```

So basically i want to get all the boards where owner.name is Joker for example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Why aren't you using collections to find the items with the correct owner?

Comment: @RossWilson its Laravel 5.4

Comment: There's a number of things you are doing that don't even remotely follow how Laravel works... read the docs dude.

Comment: @upful I had tried but i could not find the right coding for that. I am still learning. I have been trying since morning. Its already the next day here. Can you show me how its done using collections. thanks

Comment: @upful its easy when using sql database but i find it difficult when using mongoDB.

Comment: Well part of the problem might be Laravel only supports the following DB types: MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, SQL Server

Comment: @upful i have been asked to develop an application using mongodb for my final year project. I did some research and found that (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) may be used by laravel to communicate with the mongoDB database. Now i have only less than two weeks to complete the project. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the reason you're getting all of the values is because you've got:

```
->with(compact('boards', ...))
```

This essentially translates to:

```
->with(['boards' => $boards]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Try something like:

```
$s = 'Tom Cruise';
$user = Auth::User();
$boards = Board::all()->filter(function ($board) use ($s) {
    return str_contains($board['owner']['name'], $s);
});

return view('layouts.board', compact('user', 'boards'));
```

Here is the docs for the `filter` function:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter

Also, you might find this series helpful:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this in the morning but it returned empty. I tried this again and same result.

Comment: I've edited my question. In the example you were look for a string that was identical to "Tom Cruise", however, in your `json` you have  "Board by Tom Cruise". In my new example you're only checking to see if the name contains "Tom Cruise".

Comment: sorry to bother you mate but i get this error this time `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: @AatishKumar Updated